# Custom order of Taxonomy Terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm querying a custom post type and displaying all posts by terms (basically posts by category) as follows, everything is working fine EXCEPT for some reason no matter how I write the tax_query array, I can't  seem to get the order of the terms to change (ASC and DESC don't change anything).

Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong here?

```
$temp_query = $wp_query;

$custom_terms = get_terms('instruction_categories');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'instruction-sheets',
        'orderby' => 'name', // order of the products
        'order'  => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'instruction_categories',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                'hide_empty' => 1,
                'orderby' => $custom_term->name,
                'order' => 'ASC', // switching to DESC should reverse order, but doesnt
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo 'Region '.$custom_term->name.'';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue, here's how I  ended up solving this. I installed the [WP  Term Order plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-order/) and then used the following code, the  magic happens  in the 'orderby' => 'order'  line  where  the  'order' is being pulled from the drag and drop menu order functionality in the admin added by the plugin.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('instruction_categories');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'instruction-sheets',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'meta_key' => $custome_term->slug,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'instruction_categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'order',
            //  'order' => 'DESC',
        ),
    ),
 );


 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {

 while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

Then enter whatever code you need to show for parts of your post content, and then don't forget to close  the whole thing out  with:

```
    endwhile; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query arguments need revision.  The value for `orderby` should be `meta_value` or `meta_value_num` for a numeric sort.

You also need a `meta_key` set in your arguments array and in your case that should be set to the value of `$custom_term->slug`.

Untested arguments for your query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'instruction-sheets',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // Change #1
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'meta_key' => $custome_term->slug,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'instruction_categories',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            'hide_empty' => 1,
        ),
    ),
 );
```

WP Codex reference for sorting:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly, this still didn't solve the issue, though it may still have been a contributor, I've altered my code with your 'meta_value' tip.  I've solved this in a round-about  way by using a plug-in to add  a menu-order column to  the terms list in the admin which  is  drag and drop, then by simply using 'orderby' =>  'order', the list will reflect the admin's drag and drop order. Thanks again.

Comment: Roger that - I think I see why.  I inadvertently left the order and orderby args in the tax query array which would foul the query.  Edited above if you want to try it.